# Tidal locking of celestial bodies

Tags: the-moon

Generally moon always faces the same side towards the Earth. People say it is tidally locked. How is any body in space tidally locked and is this forever?

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange!
If your only question is how tidal locking works, I don't think it will be better explained here than it already is on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking). If you have a more specific question about tidal locking or something you don't fully understand, feel free to update your question.

Comment: Astronomy Stack Exchange has [86 posts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tidal+locking%22) that contain "tidal locking" and [186 posts](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tidally+locked%22) that contain "tidally locked". Rather than ask about it here, it would be better to read several of those questions and answers first (as well as checking Wikipedia). So I' voting to close.

Comment: @uhoh I've checked them a little bit, but none of them explains the phenomenon. Even if there is, the question should be closed as its dupe, and not with the current reasons. Alternatively, maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) content would be also useful.

Comment: Welcome Korlam! Could you check please this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking ? The site tries to answer questions which could not be answered easily by googling or by wikipedia. **Simply check the page and inject into the question, what you did not found there.**

Comment: @peterh: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32434/29347 unless you've been here a while...